# How to invoke a `find` on a set of iterators, looking up by what the iterator points to?

Tags: c++, list, search, c++17, unordered-set

In c++17, I was trying the following to have both an ordered list of pairs, as well as a means of rapidly being able to find random entries in this list based on the first element in the pair.   The idea was to create a class where ordinary iteration through the pairs would be in a fixed order, while still having efficient random access to them.  The entries in unordered_list are intended to only be iterators into ordered_list, and ignoring thread safety implications, ordered_list and unordered_list would always be updated together.  Here is a code fragment similar to what I was trying:

```
class ordered_pairs {
public:
    typedef std::list<std::string, std::string> list_t;

    struct iterator_hash {
        std::size_t operator()(const list_t::iterator &it) const; // hash of first element in pair
        std::size_t operator()(const std::string &s) const;
    };
    struct iterator_eq {
        bool operator()(const list_t::iterator &left, const list_t::iterator &right) const; // compares first elements of each pair
        bool operator()(const list_t::iterator &left, const std::string &right) const; // compares first element to a string
    };

    list_it::iterator find(const std::string &s)
    {
        auto iter = unordered_list.find(s);
        if (iter == unordered_list.end()) {
            return ordered_list.end();
        } else {
            return *iter;
        }
    }
    ...
private:
    std::unordered_set<list_t::iterator, iterator_hash, iterator_eq> unordered_list;
    list_t ordered_list;
};
```

The problem I am finding,however, is in my `find()` method, the compiler complains about being unable to convert a `std::string` into the iterator type that is stored in `ordered_list`.   I had thought if I overloaded the `operator()` in `iterator_hash` and `iterator_eq` to take string arguments as well as iterators, I would be able to do fast searches for entries in the set.  However, this is not the case.

The only fix for this that I have found so far is to change find as follows:

```
list_it::iterator find(const std::string &s)
{
    list_t dummy;
    dummy.insert(std::pair(s,""));
    auto iter = unordered_list.find(dumy.begin());
    if (iter == unordered_list.end()) {
        return ordered_list.end();
    } else {
        return *iter;
    }
}
```

However, this method involves creating a new list, adding an element to it just to get an iterator for it, and adding the element to that list would invoke a dynamic heap allocation (and free upon exiting the function).  Is there some way to search for iterators in my `unordered_list` where I could just search by the initial string?

Please do not hesitate to ask questions in the comments below if my question is unclear and I shall endeavor to clarify issues my making ammendments to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heterogeneous lookup for unordered containers is a C++20 feature ([P0919](https://wg21.link/p0919) and [P1690](https://wg21.link/p1690)). According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features), MSVC 19.23 is the only one of the major standard libraries that supports this so far.

Until C++20, the only two overloads of [`unordered_set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) are:

> ```
> iterator find( const Key& key );
> const_iterator find( const Key& key ) const;
> ```

Which is why you're getting the error you're seeing.